# rust-csv parse a string field wrapped in double quotes that contains newlines and uses double-quotes as escape character

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I have a csv similar to this (original file is proprietary, cannot share). Separator is Tab.
It contains a description column, whose text is wrapped in double quotes, can contain quoted strings, where, wait for it, escape sequence is also double quote.

```
id  description other_field
12 "Some Description"  34
56 "Some
Multiline
""With Escaped Stuff""
Description"    78
```

I am parsing the file with this code

```
let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
.from_reader(file)
.deserialize().unwrap();
```

I'm consistently getting CSV deserialize error :
`CSV deserialize error: record 43747 (line: 43748, byte: 21082563): missing field 'id'`

I tried using `flexible(true)`, `double_quotes(true)` with no luck.

Is it possible to parse this type of field, and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually the issue was unrelated, `rust-serde` perfectly parses this. Just forgot to define the delimiter (tab in this case). This code works :

```
let mut reader = csv::ReaderBuilder::new()
.delimiter(b'\t')
.from_reader(file)
.deserialize().unwrap();
```